# How do I organize a custom dict (with string elements)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I receive this dict in my system, with string values, and I need to organize it in a custom way.

```
kafka_data = {
    "flush_size": "1000",
    "branch": "develop",
    "cluster": "analytics",
    "system": "ft7",
    "topic_name": "topic_test", 
    "compatibility": "backward"
}
```

I found some infos and ways to organize elements, but in lists (not dicts) or in dicts (but with int/numbers).

The expected output would be like this:

```
kafka_data_expected = {
    "topic_name": "topic_test", 
    "system": "ft7",
    "cluster": "analytics",
    "branch": "develop",
    "compatibility": "backward",
    "flush_size": "1000",
}
```

Comment: Why does the order matter at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the order may matter when writing a JSON file, for example, as the interpreting party may have ordered dictionaries as a matter of course. The question is valid.

Comment: @Grismar I wasn't asking why the order _may_ matter, I was asking the OP why it _does_, in their context. JSON objects aren't semantically ordered either.

Comment: Although the order of JSON is not required by RFC 7159, many implementations preserve order and it's fairly commonly relied upon, as recognised by the developers of Python, who have elevated ordering from being a side-effect to being the intended effect since Python 3.7. I think *why* is irrelevant, since OP is using Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply recreate the dictionary:

```
kafka_data = {
    "flush_size": "1000",
    "branch": "develop",
    "cluster": "analytics",
    "system": "ft7",
    "topic_name": "topic_test", 
    "compatibility": "backward"
}

kafka_data_expected = {k: kafka_data[k] for k in (
    'topic_name', 'system', 'cluster', 'branch', 'compatibility', 'flush_size')}

print(kafka_data_expected)
```

Result:

```
{'topic_name': 'topic_test', 'system': 'ft7', 'cluster': 'analytics', 'branch': 'develop', 
 'compatibility': 'backward', 'flush_size': '1000'}
```

Dictionaries in Python have maintained insertion order since 3.7 and in practice already did so in CPython 3.6, so the above should work in those versions of Python. For older versions, you'll need the `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

Having said that - you could still consider using `OrderedDict` if you want to be very clear about your intentions, and want your code to be even more future-proof.